# To map on the array in this.state

Tags: javascript

I have the array called `homes` in `this.state`. I am updating it in `componentDidMount`. I am pushing an object in that array. Then, I am displaying it in the `render` function.

I am getting an error that says

```
map.homes is not a function
```

I have tried using ES5 normal `map` function

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      homes:[], 
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let obj1 = {
      id:1,
      Name:"Samar"
    }
    this.setState({
      homes : this.state.homes.push(obj1)
    })
    console.log("DATA IN ARRAY",this.state.homes);
  }

  render() {
    const homes = this.state;
    return(
      <div>
        ORIGINAL ARRAY
          {
            homes && homes.map((data) => {
              return (
          <div> {data}  </div>
        );
            }) 
          }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I think it should display object properties

Comment: If `state` has a property `homes` and you say `const homes = this.state;`, then your array is under `homes.homes`. Else you'd have to say `const homes = this.state.homes;`.

Comment: i tried that still it has same error

Comment: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) != [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: yeah it says homes.map is not a function

Comment: @Thomas has the answer. `.push()` returns a number, the new array length, not the updated array. So you overwrite the array with a number and numbers do not have the map method. Afaik, the best practice in react is to spread the state into a new array and add the element there. Never manipulate this.state directly.

Comment: When i did,
const new_array =[...this.state.homes]; 
It says "this.state.homes" is not iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class should work properly if you revise it to the following (here's a live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-star-l2vhv)):

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    homes: []
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const obj1 = {
      id: 1,
      Name: 'Samar'
    }

    this.setState(
      ({ homes }) => ({
        homes: [...homes, obj1]
      })
    )
  }

  render () {
    const { homes } = this.state

    return (
      <ul>
        {homes.map(
          ({ id, Name }) => (
            <li key={id}>{Name}</li>
          )
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Changes:

- [Destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) `homes` from `this.state` within `render()` so that the variable references `this.state.homes` instead of `this.state` like it erroneously did in your question.
- Updated the reference of `this.state.homes` within `setState()` by using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals), allowing the component to extend [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) instead of `React.Component`.
- Moved initialization of `state` to an [instance field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Public_instance_fields) so that the component can define the `constructor` implicitly.
- Used the [updater callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to perform the array insertion within `setState()` atomically.
- [Destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) `id` and `Name` within the `homes.map()` callback so that the output is no longer just `[object Object]`.